# Java - File writing/reading works on Windows but not Mac

Tags: java, io, operating-system

I'm currently developing an application that I wish to work on both Windows and other operating systems.

I have run into a problem where the files that are being called from folders in my program are not appearing on macOS, but ARE appearing on Windows.

All of my files are being written and read the same way as this example GUI code:

```java
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    
    public GUI()  {
        this.setTitle("test");
        this.setSize(500,349);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("assets/test.png"));
        
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(20,50,250));

        this.getContentPane().add(imageLabel);
        
        this.setSize(500, 350);
        
    }
}
```

On Windows, the GUI program looks like this:

[image]

On MacOS, the GUI program looks like this:

[image]

I would like to add that these are being run on the operating systems via a Runnable Jar file exported from Eclipse IDE. The version that is being used is JavaSE-1.8.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question but JavaSE-1.8 was the latest version of Java until the versions 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 and 16 came out :)

Comment: Your application should in theory behave the same regardless of the OS. I doubt the issue is file read as the window is shown after all - or do you see some exception popping up? How do you run your GUI actually?

But what I am missing (and I may be wrong there): You do not define any layout manager. Is it Windows that comes with a suitable default while it is not present on MacOS?

Comment: can you check the names of "assets" and "test.png" in the file system? are you using the same case?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same case for all of the images.

Comment: is your assets directory in the following path : src/main/resources? if it is, try also new ImageIcon("/assets/test.png")

Comment: My image is in the path /projectname/assets/test.png
Edit: my other path is /projectname/src/GUI.java

Comment: Is the `assets` folder in the current directory when you execute your JAR file? It needs to be. @tremendous7 `new ImageIcon(String)` refers to a filename, not a resource name.

Comment: Yes, it is in the same directory. It looks like this: https://gyazo.com/1efd336eb52c5e85ab73b1690af15e68

Comment: I didn't ask whether it was in the same directory as your JAR file. Read what I actually wrote. I asked whether it was in the *current* directory when you execute. It isn't the same thing.

Comment: It is, sorry about the confusion. The screenshot was of the current directory. If I am mistaking your words, what do you mean by the difference? I am launching the jar file that was shown in the folder, which is in the same directory as the assets folder

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**The problem line lies here:**

```java
imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("assets/test.png"));
```

**My Solution:**

```java
imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("test.png")));
```

**Explaination:**

My original intention was to somehow incorporate the resources of the program itself to work together with the JAR executable. In my testing (I'm new with making executables), I found that nothing would work unless I had a separate folder "assets" that the user would also download with the jar file. While this solution did work for a little bit, some reading and writing seemed to be different on some machines.

In order for this to work, *you **must** add the "assets" folder or whatever folder has your images inside of them to your Java Build Path.*

From here, it works on all tested machines; Windows and MacOS.